# How can I share a windows 7 directory with a specific network card?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-networking

I have trusted computer that is connected with my laptop through the ethernet card. I want to share a directory with the said computer without setting up passwords(The network is physically isolated), but I also dont want the share to be accesible through my wireless card.

In other words, I want to make a windows share accessible through only one network. How can I do this in windows 7?

Comment: It is my understanding that when a folder is set to be shared its for a specific network connection by default.  You can also disable sharing while your connected to your wireless connection ( even if my first statement is false ).

Comment: I dont see an option to choose the network card. When I click on 'share with' all I see is 'nobody', 'homegroup' or specific people. It seems that it is only possible to share on all networks or none

Comment: When the network is connected your asked if its "Public" or "Private" and within the network control center able to fine tune other settings.  As I said if you disable sharing while on the WiFI connection then enable it on the hardline then sharing is only enabled when you want it.